# Accessing an object function from a parent widget's function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

I'm making a large program in Python and using PyQt for the GUI. The whole program is divided into different modules so that different people can work on it simultaneously without interfering with the other people's work.

I am working on 3 different modules right now. 1 is the main program window that handles the basic UI and assigns widgets so the main window (this is not important, just so you know why the code doesn't look like a full program.)

First is the widget:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from CustomButton import HoverButton  #just a custom button class
from CustomGif import LblLoadingGif  #where things go wrong

class Page1(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lbl1GIF = LblLoadingGif(self)
        self.lbl1GIF.move(400, 45)

        self.btnStart = HoverButton(self)
        self.btnStart.setText('Start')
        self.btnStart.move(35, 400)
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.actStartGif)
        #the code below works, but then I can only perform 1 action with each button
        #self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.lbl1GIF.actStart)

    def actStartGif(self):
        self.lbl1GIF.actStart
```

The code for the custom GIF looks as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class LblLoadingGif(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: url();')
        self.setScaledContents(True)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.movLoadGif = QtGui.QMovie('Resources_Images/Loading6.gif', QtCore.QByteArray())
        self.movLoadGif.setCacheMode(QtGui.QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movLoadGif.setSpeed(100)
        self.setMovie(self.movLoadGif)
        self.hide()

    def actStart(self, event):
        #print('test1')
        self.show()
        self.movLoadGif.start()

    def actStop(self, event):
        #print('test1')
        self.hide()
        self.movLoadGif.stop()
```

So the problem is that I can use the actStart function just fine when I call it from the button click directly, but not when I call it through another function. I have used a lot of different variations of brackets, self, Page1 when calling the actStart of the custom gif from withing the actStartGif function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So the call to self.lbl1GIF.actStart in side actStartGif fails, right? 
What is the actual error you get? 
1) actStart is a function so you should add parentheses: self.lbl1GIF.actStart().  
2) And since actStart seems to expect an event parameter (which is not used apparently), you should also pass that one: self.lbl1GIF.actStart(None)

Comment: PERFECT! adding the '(None)' parentheses solved it. But to answer your question, I get no response from calling the function.
The reason for this, I think, is because I use a module as the outline of the main program and then just load widgets into it every time. This help when a few people want to work different pages without having to worry about the overlaying program or that their code clashes with each other. this is why the class is just named Page1 and there is no 'if __name__ == '__main__':' code given.
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use connect it is necessary to pass the name of the function since internally it is in charge of calling it, in your case you have to call it directly so you will have to pass its parameters, in this case *event*:

```
self.lbl1GIF.actStart({your value for event})
```

I do not understand why you use event for what happens to you None:

```
def actStartGif(self):
    self.lbl1GIF.actStart(None)
```

Comment: This is the first time I have had to use PyQt so I am new to using objects and object related functions. The '(None)' parentheses did the trick perfectly, thanks